# Bonitasoft- repository from webinar

Tags: github, bonita

July 26th Nonitasoft organized a webinar "All Aboard the Bonita Extres- From menu to kitchen".
Thalia, who led the meeting, metioned that the Bonita project "acme-restaurant-sample" will be available on GitHub.
I was looking for it, but cannot find it.
Can anyone help?

I was looking on GitHub via "Bonitasoft" and via name of the project.